# Swift - how to make protocol to be both class and need to adopt certain type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am trying to make protocol that need to have certain type using `Self == MyCustomClass`. But this protocol is used as delegate type and weak constraint requires it to be also class-only protocol with P`rotocolName : class`

I have tried something like this

```
protocol MusicPlayerViewDelegate : class where Self == MusicPlayerController {
}
```

and then:

```
weak var delegate : MusicPlayerViewDelegate?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your protocol needs to extends NSObjectProtocol to be able to use weak with it.
You can also try to make MusicPlayerController extend NSObject but I'm not sure it will work.